# For function not working

Tags: php, html, css

The code should take contents between `10872` to `10878` but it only takes `10872` content.

Where is the error? Could you help me?

> ```
> <?php
> error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
> set_time_limit(999999);
> mysql_select_db("test",mysql_connect("localhost","test","test"));
>           @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'LATIN5'");
>           @mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET LATIN5");
>           @mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'latin5_turkish_ci'");
>
> Function duzenle($text){
> $gkod   = array('<FONT size=2 face?"Verdana, Arial, Helvatica, sans-serif">','</FONT>','</DIV>','<DIV>','<DIV>');
> $dkod   = array('','','<br />','');
> $ykod   = str_replace($gkod,$dkod,$text);
> return $ykod;
> }
>
> $nereden = "10872";
> $nereye = "10878";
>
> for($a=$nereden; $a<=nereye; $a++){
> $site = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
> $link = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/$a";
> $parcala = '@<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">(.*?)<div class="post-taglist">@si';
>
>
>
> $botara = file_get_contents($link);
>   preg_match_all($parcala,$botara,$baslik);
>
>
>
> $botbaslik = addslashes($baslik[1][0]);
>
> $save = mysql_query("insert into deneme (yazi) values 
> ('$botbaslik')");
>
> if($save){
>   echo"<p style='color :green'> $botbaslik Basariyla eklendi</p>";
>   }else{
>   echo"<p style='color :red'> $botbaslik Basariyla eklenmedi</p>";
>   }
> }
>
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: `$a<=nereye` should probably be `$a < $nereye`

Comment: Try removing the qoutes ""

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley not worked :(

Comment: @FahadRaufMalik which qoutes

Comment: $nereden = "10872"; to $nereden = 10872;
$nereye = "10878"; to  $nereye = 10878;

Comment: @FahadRaufMalik not worked. now i see blank page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you write

```
   $nereden = "10872";
   $nereye = "10878";

  for($a=$nereden; $a<=nereye; $a++){ // put $a<=$nereye insted of $a<=nereye
   $site = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
     $link = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/$a";
```

$variable ($) must in php with variable value

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare it in int variable like this,

```
$nereden = 10872;
$nereye = 10878;
```

if you decare it in string it's will compare with `$nereden="1"` and `$nereye ="1"` and it's run on one time.

Comment: Actually, PHP will cast the whole string to int, not just the first digit. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php